# How to run async coroutines from init, wait until it is complete

Tags: python, redis, python-asyncio

I am connecting to aioredis from `__init__` (I do not want to move it out since this means I have to some extra major changes). How can I wait for aioredis connection `task` in below `__init__` example code and have it print `self.sub` and `self.pub` object? Currently it gives an error saying

> abc.py:42> exception=AttributeError("'S' object has no attribute
>   'pub'")

I do see redis connections created and coro `create_connetion` done.

Is there a way to call blocking asyncio calls from `__init__`. If I replace `asyncio.wait` with `asyncio.run_until_complete` I get an error that roughly says

> loop is already running.

`asyncio.gather` is

```
import sys, json
from addict import Dict
import asyncio
import aioredis

class S():
    def __init__(self, opts):
        print(asyncio.Task.all_tasks())
        task = asyncio.wait(asyncio.create_task(self.create_connection()), return_when="ALL_COMPLETED")
        print(asyncio.Task.all_tasks())
        print(task)
        print(self.pub, self.sub)

    async def receive_message(self, channel):
        while await channel.wait_message():
            message = await channel.get_json()
            await asyncio.create_task(self.callback_loop(Dict(json.loads(message))))

    async def run_s(self):
        asyncio.create_task(self.listen())
        async def callback_loop(msg):
            print(msg)

        self.callback_loop = callback_loop

    async def create_connection(self):
        self.pub = await aioredis.create_redis("redis://c8:7070/0", password="abc")
        self.sub = await aioredis.create_redis("redis://c8:7070/0", password="abc")
        self.db = await aioredis.create_redis("redis://c8:7070/0", password="abc")
        self.listener = await self.sub.subscribe(f"abc")

    async def listen(self):
        self.tsk = asyncio.ensure_future(self.receive_message(self.listener[0]))
        await self.tsk

async def periodic(): #test function to show current tasks
    number = 5
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(number)
        print(asyncio.Task.all_tasks())

async def main(opts):
    loop.create_task(periodic())
    s = S(opts)
    print(s.pub, s.sub)
    loop.create_task(s.run_s())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    main_task = loop.create_task(main(sys.argv[1:]))
    loop.run_forever() #I DONT WANT TO MOVE THIS UNLESS IT IS NECESSARY
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is to make sure the function create_connections runs to completion BEFORE the S constructor.  A way to do that is to rearrange your code a little bit.  Move the create_connections function outside the class:

```
async def create_connection():
    pub = await aioredis.create_redis("redis://c8:7070/0", password="abc")
    sub = await aioredis.create_redis("redis://c8:7070/0", password="abc")
    db = await aioredis.create_redis("redis://c8:7070/0", password="abc")
    listener = await self.sub.subscribe(f"abc")
    return pub, sub, db, listener
```

Now await that function before constructing S.  So your main function becomes:

```
async def main(opts):
    loop.create_task(periodic())
    x = await create_connections()
    s = S(opts, x)  # pass the result of create_connections to S
    print(s.pub, s.sub)
    loop.create_task(s.run_s())
```

Now modify the S constructor to receive the objects created:

```
def __init__(self, opts, x):
    self.pub, self.sub, self.db, self.listener = x
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the return_when argument and the call to asyncio.wait.  The create_connections function doesn't launch a set of parallel tasks, but rather awaits each of the calls before moving on to the next one.  Perhaps you could improve performance by running the four calls in parallel but that's a different question.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, the only reason I used `asyncio.wait` is because I was not able to use `await` in `__init__`. Your suggestion looks nice. Let me try it. I feel this problem would not have existed is I were able to have `__init__` coroutines(i.e `async __init__(self):`)